# Why do I need "out" with a string in C#?

Tags: c#

I know `string` is a value type in C#. I understand everything in C# are passed by value.

But if it's a value type anyway there is no need 'out' or 'ref', right?

Comment: And neither `out` nor `ref` is exclusive for either Value or Reference types.

Comment: @Hermal: Seems like "Can I pass it by value?" is the question (although Elad used awkward word order)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String is a reference type (a class) as others have pointed out. It's just that it's immutable, which makes it sometimes feel like a value type *in some ways*.

You can pass a string argument by reference or by value, just as with any other parameter. It's worth being absolutely clear about the difference between these two concepts. I have two articles on the topic:

- [Reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html)
- [Parameter passing in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html)

It's worth becoming really familiar with this topic (and reading articles other than mine, of course) - understanding the difference between reference types and value types is absolutely *key* in C#, and so is understanding parameter passing (and even what a simple assignment statement means).

Answer (score 6):

String is not a value type. It's an immutable sealed reference type.

The [MSDN Page on String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) is probably worth a read.

Answer (score 3):

The wrong things you "know" will mess you up.

`System.String` is immutable, but it is NOT a value type.

Beyond that, `ref`/`out` can be used with either value or reference types.  They're needed when you want to replace the ENTIRE object.  They're not needed if you just want to read from the object.  If you want to change members of the object, then `ref` is needed for a value type but not for a reference type.

From this we conclude that if you just want to read a `string`, you should pass it by value (the value is a reference to the string content, but it's not linked to the original string variable).  But if you want to replace the string with a different one, use `ref`.  And if there isn't any string to begin with, it's first assigned inside the function, use `out`.

Comment: Modifying a variable passed with "out" or "ref" doesn't change *any* object. It changes *the aliased variable*. Variables are not objects; variables *contain* objects, or references to objects.

Comment: @EricLippert: I never said changes were made to the object.

Comment: @BenVoigt, out of curiosity, why are you using C++-like `::` as a namespace delimiter?

Comment: Right -- I was clarifying "they're needed when you want to replace the entire object". The way you "replace" the object is to *change a variable*. No *object* changes; variables are not objects.

Comment: @svick: Because I have C++/CLI on the brain, apparently.

Comment: @svick: Fun fact: it is legal to replace a "." with a "::" in C# provided that the identifier on the left side is an "extern alias" or a "using alias" or the magic word "global". See section 9.7 of the specification for details.

Comment: @EricLippert, that's interesting. I didn't even know extern aliases existed.

Answer (score 3):

You have to distinguish between *reference types* and *passing by reference*, as they are quite different things.

A string is a reference type, which means that it's an object allocated on the heap, which you access using a reference.

When you pass something by reference, it's the *variable* that you are passing, not the value that the variable contains. You pass a variable by reference when you need to change the value of the variable, regardless of whether the value is a value type or if it's a reference to an object.

The default for passing variables is *by value*, which for a string means that you send a copy of the reference to the string, not a copy of the string data.

Generally parameters are passed by value, it's only in some special situations that you ever need to consider passing a variable by reference. If you want to return a single value (which could alo be a reference) from a method, the return type is used. If you need to return multiple values you can use `out` or `ref`, but you can also create an object with multiple properties and return that, so you never *need* to use `out` or `ref`.